# Select column if exists else null - PSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

The following function joins dynamically different tables.

```
create or replace function unified_tables() returns table(  
                      1         TEXT
                    , 2         TEXT
                    , 3         TEXT
                    , 4         TEXT
                    , 5         JSONB
                    , 6         BIGINT
                    , 7         BIGINT
                    , 8         TEXT
                    , 9         TEXT
                    , 10        TIMESTAMPTZ
                    )
as
$$
declare
  a record;
begin
  for a in select table_schema
                    from information_schema.tables
                    where table_name = 'name' 
  loop
     return query 
        execute format('select  %L as source_schema,  *  from %I.name', a.table_schema,  a.table_schema);
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately, not all the tables called have all the columns specified in RETURNS TABLE.

Precisely, there are 15 tables (the loop goes over 200+ tables) missing the column 2, two tables missing the column 4, and five tables missing the column 9.

Future tables entering the loop might miss columns as well. I do not have control on the source structure.

**How can I keep using the function adding a null value for the missing columns so to maintain the structure defined in the RETURNS TABLE?**

Comment: If the answer provided resolved your issue please accept it. This helps future questioners having the same or similar issues. Do not just leave resolved issues in an open/active status. If  the issue was not resolved then what remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to be able to write a query that will have give you what you want. You will need to build in code. The simplest way is using information_schema.columns of your target table with the list of desired column names. This in itself creates an issue as "future tables entering the loop might miss columns as well" and you may not know what those columns are in advance, also the maintenance issue when the necessary columns change. Now this does not mean there is there is not a simple answer. Just not what you have to query.  
The easiest way is to create a template table with the column names and data types needed. Then a function to join the template columns with the target table columns. For column maintenance then you only need to alter the template table. (See [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0b68b232b76ac78eadc8b38fec960a41))

```
create table unified_def
             (c1    text
             ,c2    text
             ,c3    text
             ,c4    text
             ,c5    jsonb
             ,c6    bigint
             ,c7    bigint
             ,c8    text
             ,c9    text
             ,c10   timestamptz
             );   

create or replace 
function unified_tables(target_table_in text) 
 returns setof unified_def
 language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
   def_cur cursor( c_tgt_table text ) for  
          with ud(column_name,data_type, ordinal_position) as 
               ( select column_name,data_type,ordinal_position  
                   from information_schema.columns 
                  where table_name = 'unified_def' 
                   order by ordinal_position         
               )  --select * from ud
             , tgt (column_name) as 
               ( select column_name 
                   from information_schema.columns        
                  where table_name = c_tgt_table 
               ) --select * from tgt
          select ud.column_name cname
               , tgt.column_name tname
               , ud.data_type
            from ud left join tgt on (ud.column_name = tgt.column_name);

   l_from     text = ' from <tbl>';
   l_sep      text = '';
   l_stmt     text = 'select '; 
begin
     for cdef in def_cur(target_table_in) 
     loop 
         l_stmt =  l_stmt || l_sep 
               ||  coalesce(cdef.tname, 'null::' || cdef.data_type); 
         l_sep  = ',';
     end loop; 
     
     l_stmt = l_stmt || replace (l_from, '<tbl>', target_table_in);
    
     raise notice E'Run Statement \n%', l_stmt; 
     return query execute l_stmt;
end;
$$;
```

*NOTE:* The above function assumes data type compatibility between the template and the target tables. If there is a case where this does not hold true, then additional code would be required to handle the situation. In any case the eventual return type ***must*** agree with the definition of the template table.